# What does the one in 'tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1) mean?

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a game and there is this part of the code I don't understand.`tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)`
What does the number after "-topmost" mean? I changed the number to 0 and 255, yet there is no difference. Why is that?

- I also checked the tkinter documentation and I can't find the function.

Comment: Have you tried reading the tkinter documentation for that function?

Comment: Can you give the web URL? I can't find the function in the tkinter documentation, even using the quick search.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the function's quite well hidden and (I think) only works on Python.

`tk.wm_attributes()` sets settings for tkinter to use for drawing the app. `-topmost` is an option to make the window always be on top of all the other windows, and zero is considered false while all other numbers are true.

So in other words, `tk.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)` means "Yes, do draw the window on top of all the others."

Comment: The `topmost` option works in any language that supports tk, though the syntax will be slightly different in different languages of course.

Answer (score 0):

The `topmost` attribute requires a value that can be converted to `True` or `False` in the tcl language. `1` or any other number greater than zero evaluates to `True`. `0` will evaluate to False.

So, `tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)` sets the `topmost` option on, and a value of `0` turns it off.